# "What if I come back" vs "what if I came back"

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

What is more grammatically correct? and what are their differences?

> What if I *come* back for you?
>
> Or
>
> What if I *came* back for you?

Same goes here:

> What if I *told* you...?
>
> Or
>
> What if I *tell* you...?

Comment: All are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all correct, but they have different meanings.

"What if I come back for you" is an offer. "I am offering to come back for you, if ...".

"What if I came back for you" is weaker, a request for information. "Tell me what you would do if I came back for you, then I will decide". It's hypothetical.

I think in many cases the difference in meaning is subtle and not very important.